# In Postgres, how can I average the latest 5 scores per user?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I am stuck on a query in Postgres and am getting pretty frustrated. I have a table called scores with three columns:

```
score, user_id and date
```

And I want to get the average of all users last 5 scores. This query doesn't exactly get me that:

```
SELECT user_id, 
       ROUND( AVG( score )::numeric, 2) as sc_avg
FROM 
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) AS r,
    sc.*
    from mg.scores sc
WHERE score IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY date DESC) AS x
WHERE x.r >= 5
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Is there a better way to limit the last 5 jobs per user?

Comment: You need to add the `ORDER BY date DESC` to the `over()` clause, otherwise the row_number() doesn't return what you think (btw: `date` is a *horrible* name for a column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **`ORDER BY`** clause has to go into the window function.
And since your order is **descending**, it needs to be **<=** instead of **>=**:

```
SELECT user_id, round(avg(score)::numeric, 2) AS sc_avg
FROM  (
   SELECT *
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date DESC) AS rn
   FROM   mg.scores
   WHERE  score IS NOT NULL
   ) AS x
WHERE  x.rn <= 5
GROUP  BY user_id;
```

If `date` can be `NULL`, use `ORDER BY date DESC NULLS LAST`. See:

- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)