# In Postgres, latest 5 scores per user returning username

Tags: postgresql

Based on [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902762/in-postgres-how-can-i-average-the-latest-5-scores-per-user) how is the query modified to return the user's name from a foreign table via the user_id? Here's the sql from the answer of the linked thread:

```
SELECT user_id, round(avg(score)::numeric, 2) AS sc_avg
FROM  (
   SELECT *
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date DESC) AS rn
   FROM   mg.scores
   WHERE  score IS NOT NULL
   ) AS x
WHERE  x.rn <= 5
GROUP  BY user_id;
```

Comment: if the username is i score which i doubt , you would get from score but usually you have a usertable to join

Comment: @nbk Correct. That's the question. How does the query change to retrieve the user's name from a Users table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join then user table to the subselect

```
SELECT x.user_id,u.user_name, round(avg(score)::numeric, 2) AS sc_avg
FROM  (
   SELECT *
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date DESC) AS rn
   FROM   mg.scores
   WHERE  score IS NOT NULL
   ) AS x 
JOIN user u ON x.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE  x.rn <= 5
GROUP  BY user_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

First aggregate, then join:

```sql
SELECT u.name, s.*
FROM  (
   SELECT user_id, round(avg(score)::numeric, 2) AS sc_avg
   FROM  (
      SELECT user_id, score
           , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date DESC NULLS LAST) AS rn
      FROM   mg.scores
      WHERE  score IS NOT NULL
      ) AS sub
   WHERE  x.rn <= 5
   GROUP  BY user_id
   ) s
JOIN   users u ON u.user_id = x.user_id;
```

But the best solution depends on undisclosed details. If referential integrity is not guaranteed, you might use a `LEFT JOIN`. If you only want results for a few given users a different query is much more efficient ...

Especially if some users might not have any scores (yet), this form is the safe course of action (preserving all users):

```sql
SELECT u.user_id, u.name, s.*
FROM   users u
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT round(avg(score)::numeric, 2) AS sc_avg
   FROM  (
      SELECT s.score
      FROM   mg.scores s
      WHERE  s.user_id = u.user_id
      AND    s.score IS NOT NULL
      ORDER  BY s.date DESC NULLS LAST
      LIMIT  5
      ) AS sub
   ) s ON true;
```

See:

- [What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-a-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Either way, have an index on `mg.scores (user_id, date DESC NULLS LAST)` or similar. And on `users (user_id)`. Details depend on the full case.